# Using keyword to search date

Tags: mysql, date

If I have a list of data as following:

```
id      name          postdate      
46      apple         2011-02-20     
47      orange        2011-01-12      
49      banana        2008-07-01
```

How do I make a MYSQL search query base on year and date?

I tried use this query to search, but ONLY `SELECT * FROM table WHERE post date like '%2008-07-01 %';` seems to work without problems.

This query doesn't work...

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE post date like '%2008%';
Error: Incorrect data value: '%2004%' for column postdate
```

I need a query can work for both cases.

Answer (score 0):

If `postdate` is of type `DATE`, you could use the `EXTRACT` function, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM postdate) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM (DATE '2008-01-01'))
```

Maybe it would be better to distinct this two cases, wether a year only is searched or a full date.